# Is it possible to deactivate/remove/uninstall a default client side webpart?

Tags: web-part, modern-pages

I'm trying to deactivate/remove/uninstall a **default** Client Side Web-Part (the Yammer one) in modern pages and I don't find a way to do it:

[image]

I would like the **Yammer option to be not visible** in the menu.
Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Look at this article [Uninstall (Remove) The Apps Or Client Side Webpart (SPFx) In SharePoint Online](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uninstall-remove-the-apps-or-client-side-webpart-spfx-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov: this talks about custom web parts. But he is asking for included web parts in the SPFx.

Comment: I added a uservoice request for the SPFx team, since I am very sure, that this is not possible!

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/31375828-give-opportunity-to-remove-or-deactivate-standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think so there is any way to remove those OOTB shipped client side web parts. But as a workaround you can inject custom CSS to your page using SPFx Extensions - Application Customizer (still in preview so workaround doesnt apply to production tenant) to hide the element from the page.

The yammer webpart render as button having following code. Use the css selector to hide it.

```
<button class="CanvasToolboxItem CanvasToolboxItemFloat" title="Display Yammer conversations." data-automation-id="YammerEmbedWebPartToolboxItem" tabindex="0" style="">
    <i role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" data-icon-name="YammerLogo" class="ms-Icon css-liugll CanvasToolboxItem-icon"></i>
    <div data-automation-id="less-text" title="Yammer feed" class="CanvasToolboxItem-title">Yammer feed</div>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Yes, we already thought about this workaround, but as the SPFx Extensions are not in GA status, we don't want to use it.

Comment: As a trick, your custom client side web part can also inject script on modern page but even i wont recommend that way, using Extensions will be the preferred way but since we know its in RC mode right now, we cant implement it for production tenants as of now. You may have to wait for couples of weeks to get GA of Extensions.

Comment: Hi again, as SPFx Extensions are now in GA status, I did it using CSS selectors: 
button[data-automation-id="YammerEmbedWebPartToolboxItem"] {
    display: none;
}
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a powershell command to disable web parts that don't connect to Microsoft services, but are shipped by Microsoft.

You'll use Set-SPOTenant with the parameter

```
DisabledWebpartIds <GUID>
```

See the documentation here: [Set-SPOTenant documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Set-SPOTenant?view=sharepoint-ps)

Allows administrators prevent certain, specific web parts from being added to pages or rendering on pages on which they were previously added. Currently, only Amazon Kindle, YouTube and Twitter web parts can be disabled in such a manner.

To disable a specific web part you need to enter its GUID as the parameter:

- Amazon Kindle (46698648-fcd5-41fc-9526-c7f7b2ace919)
- YouTube (544dd15b-cf3c-441b-96da-004d5a8cea1d)
- Twitter (f6fdf4f8-4a24-437b-a127-32e66a5dd9b4).

Answer (score -1):

Specifying the Client-Side Web Part icon using a font icon
Another way to set the icon of a Client-Side Web Part is by specifying the name of the font icon using the [officeFabricIconFontName](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/specify-icon-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-part/).
Example this code "Sunny", make a filter for the necessary widgets code:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces/lib/manifestSchemas/jsonSchemas/clientSideComponentManifestSchema.json",
```

"id": "e71c23c5-4ddb-40b6-9e52-d292a4d8300b",
  "componentType": "WebPart",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifestVersion": 2,

"preconfiguredEntries": [{
    "groupId": "e71c23c5-4ddb-40b6-9e52-d292a4d8300b",
    "group": { "default": "Default" },
    "title": { "default": "Weather" },
    "description": { "default": "Shows weather in the given location" },
    "officeFabricIconFontName": "Sunny",
    "properties": {
      "location": ""
    }
  }]
}
[image]

Despite its name, the officeFabricIconFontName property doesn't support all icons listed at [Office UI Fabric](http://dev.office.com/fabric/styles). Here is the list of all icons that you can use with the officeFabricIconFontName property.

Comment: What does this have to do with removing things from the menu?

Comment: @Mikhail Zhuykov: He wants to remove it not change an icon of a custom client webpart

Comment: @SebastianSchütze I already added this solution, it also did not suit, all just a person does not know what he wants http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uninstall-remove-the-apps-or-client-side-webpart-spfx-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov please read his question again. He is not talking about custom SPFx webpart but the default one. You can't remove them like you suggest with the link!