# Hide OOTB web parts

Tags: web-part, ootb

Environment: SharePoint 2019 - Modern

On my SharePoint Teams Site, I want to use only a few OOTB webparts and I'd like to hide other OOTB web parts from the web part list.

It is just to avoid the users trying to put many different web parts on the pages. The attached picture illustrates what I want if it is possible to do, hide the web parts in red for example.

Best,
Rick.

[image]

Comment: Check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225552/is-it-possible-to-deactivate-remove-uninstall-a-default-client-side-webpart